# HTML страница в массив

Tags: java, массивы, android-studio, jsoup, arraylist

```
import org.htmlparser.Node;
import org.htmlparser.NodeFilter;
import org.htmlparser.Parser;
import org.htmlparser.filters.RegexFilter;
import org.htmlparser.filters.StringFilter;
import org.htmlparser.filters.TagNameFilter;
import org.htmlparser.util.NodeList;
import org.htmlparser.util.ParserException;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class WapWeb {



     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParserException {
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
        Parser parser = new Parser("http://URLLLLL");
        parser.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        NodeFilter atrb1 = new StringFilter("-");
        NodeList nodeList = parser.parse(atrb1);

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.size(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.elementAt(i);
            System.out.println(node.toHtml());
            arr.add(i,node.toHtml());

        }

    } catch (ParserException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();

    }


}
```

}

В ответ получаю такое:

> - Мусы Джалиля (Татарская Башмаковка), 32 (
> - Шоссейная (Новоначаловский), 25 (
> - Савушкина, 4 к1 (
> - Валдайская, 12 (
> - Судостроителей, 15 (
>     30-
> - Энергетическая (Ленинский), 11 (
> - Павла Корчагина, 8 (

Вот сам html
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как разбить и положить ответ так, чтобы получить массив такого вида:
1. Татищева, 2а  |  Тек|  САВ 
 2. Боевая, 2     |Тек  |  ЖИЛ 
 3. Медиков, 5к1  |  Тек|  НАЧ

....

Получаемые с Url данные постоянно обновляются, то есть нужен динамично изменяющийся массив...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60; url=/wap/regionorders.php?id=????????H&amp;status=&amp;uid=1558893254" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wap/img/wap.css"/><title>21:54</title></head><body><p style="text-align: center"><span class="clock">21:54</span> <b>Все заказы</b><br/></p><p>- Татищева, 2а (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">САВ</span><br/>- Боевая, 2 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЖИЛ</span><br/>- Медиков, 5 к1 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">НАЧ</span><br/>- Ботвина, 30 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЯБЛ</span><br/>- Балашовская, 13 к3 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">МАР</span><br/>- Латвийская, 1Б (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">НАЧ</span><br/>- Маркина, 44 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">МАР</span><br/>- Кубанская, 70а (<span class="date">22:00</span>), <span class="plain">КУБ</span><br/>- Вокзальная площадь, 13 лит А (<span class="date">22:00</span>), <span class="plain">КАР</span><br/>- Вокзальная площадь, 13 лит А (<span class="date">22:05</span>), <span class="plain">КАР</span><br/>- Николая Островского, 146а (<span class="date">22:05</span>), <span class="plain">КУБ</span><br/>- Никольская, 11 (<span class="date">22:05</span>), <span class="plain">ЦЕН</span><br/>- Никольская, 11 (<span class="date">22:05</span>), <span class="plain">ЦЕН</span><br/>- Никольская, 11 (<span class="date">22:05</span>), <span class="plain">ЦЕН</span><br/>- Боевая, 25 (<span class="date">22:10</span>), <span class="plain">ЖИЛ</span><br/>- Боевая, 25 (<span class="date">22:10</span>), <span class="plain">ЖИЛ</span><br/>- Бертюльская, 7 (<span class="date">22:10</span>), <span class="plain">САВ</span><br/>- Школьная (Трусово), 3в (<span class="date">22:10</span>), <span class="plain">СТА</span><br/>- Шоссейная, 6а (<span class="date">22:10</span>), <span class="plain">2-Й</span><br/>- Бабаевского, 35 к2 (<span class="date">22:30</span>), <span class="plain">БАБ</span><br/>- Зеленгинская 2-я, 1 к2 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ВОС</span><br/>- Епишина, 82 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">БАК</span><br/>- Латышева, 3е к1 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">САВ</span><br/>- Бабефа, 37 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЭЛЛ</span><br/>- Ужгородская, 9 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЯБЛ</span><br/>- Красная, 14 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">БАК</span><br/>- Вокзальная площадь, 13 лит А (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КАР</span><br/>- Боевая, 25 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЖИЛ</span><br/>- Куликова, 81 к1 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ОНК</span><br/>- Анатолия Сергеева, 11 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЦЕН</span><br/>- Фиолетова, 36 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЦЕН</span><br/>- Урицкого, 5 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЦЕН</span><br/>- Сабанс Яр, 11а (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">АЭР</span><br/>- Боевая, 2 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЖИЛ</span><br/>- Калининградская, 10 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">АВТ</span><br/>- Боевая, 25 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЖИЛ</span><br/>- Минусинская, 8 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ГЕР</span><br/>- Челябинская, 22 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КУБ</span><br/>- Барсовой, 17 к2 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">БАР</span><br/>- Лычманова, 40 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">БАК</span><br/>- Вокзальная площадь, 13 лит А (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КАР</span><br/>- Плавецкий переулок, 1 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">СВО</span><br/>- Адмирала Нахимова, 48а (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">АДМ</span><br/>- Анри Барбюса, 21а (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">САВ</span><br/>- Нариманова, 2г (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">МАР</span><br/>- Генерала Армии Епишева, 65 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">АВТ</span><br/>- Льдовая, 29 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">АДМ</span><br/>- Краснодарская, 47 к1 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КУБ</span><br/>- Верещагина, 56а (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">АДМ</span><br/>- Савушкина, 4 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">САВ</span><br/>- Марии Максаковой, 39 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">САВ</span><br/>- Перекопский переулок, 15 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">СВО</span><br/>- Бориса Алексеева, 2Б (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЯБЛ</span><br/>- Звездная, 51 к1 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">3-Й</span><br/>- Школьная(Советский), 93 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">30-</span><br/>- Туркестанская, 14 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">БАР</span><br/>- Дубровинского, 64 к2 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КУБ</span><br/>- Менжинского, 6 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЖИЛ</span><br/>- Победы (Кировский), 53а/3 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КАР</span><br/>- Савушкина, 23в (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">САВ</span><br/>- Николая Островского, 55 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЖИЛ</span><br/>- Челябинская, 20а (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КУБ</span><br/>- Чернышевского, 7 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КРК</span><br/>- Боевая, 126 к10 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">АВТ</span><br/>- Куликова, 85 к3 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ОНК</span><br/>- Боевая, 25 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЖИЛ</span><br/>- Савушкина, 45а (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">САВ</span><br/>- Володарского, 4 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЦЕН</span><br/>- Акварельный переулок, 11 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">САВ</span><br/>- Генерала Армии Епишева, 4 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЖИЛ</span><br/>- Вокзальная, 19 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КАР</span><br/>- Савушкина, 4 к1 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">САВ</span><br/>- Ахматовская, 9 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЦЕН</span><br/>- Софьи Перовской, 101 к12 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ВОС</span><br/>- Свердлова, 85 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КРК</span><br/>- Кирова, 84 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КУБ</span><br/>- Советская, 2 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЦЕН</span><br/>- Немова, 34 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">30-</span><br/>- Курская, 59 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">БАР</span><br/>- Вокзальная площадь, 13 лит А (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КАР</span><br/>- Богдана Хмельницкого, 2а (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЖИЛ</span><br/>- Вокзальная площадь, 13 лит А (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КАР</span><br/>- Вокзальная площадь, 13 лит А (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КАР</span><br/>- Кубанская, 23а (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КУБ</span><br/>- Савушкина, 45а (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">САВ</span><br/>- Боевая, 62 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЖИЛ</span><br/>- Хибинская, 6 к2 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ВОЕ</span><br/>- Фиолетова, 36 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЦЕН</span><br/>- Красная Набережная, 3 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КАР</span><br/>- Аэропортовское шоссе, 45 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">АЭР</span><br/>- Рождественского, 20 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">РОЖ</span><br/>- Сибирская, 1 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">СВО</span><br/>- Савушкина, 5 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">САВ</span><br/>- Ульянова, 32 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">АДМ</span><br/>- Кирова, 7 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КРК</span><br/>- Ленина (Три Протока), 15 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">3-Й</span><br/>- Николая Островского, 55 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЖИЛ</span><br/>- Шаумяна, 20 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЦЕН</span><br/>- Зеленгинская 2-я, 3 к1 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ВОС</span><br/>- Зеленгинская 2-я, 3 к1 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ВОС</span><br/>- Максима Горького, 2Б (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЦЕН</span><br/>- Савушкина, 24а (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">САВ</span><br/>- Кирова, 51а (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">БАК</span><br/>- Савушкина, 6 к10 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">САВ</span><br/>- Рылеева, 39 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">БАР</span><br/>- Вокзальная, 19 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">КАР</span><br/>- Боевая, 25 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЖИЛ</span><br/>- Адмиралтейская, 1 к2 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЦЕН</span><br/>- Кремлёвская, 1а (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЦЕН</span><br/>- Вавилова (Советский), 12 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">АДМ</span><br/>- Ленина, 18 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ЦЕН</span><br/>- Зеленгинская 3-я, 60 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">ВОС</span><br/><span class="small">Страница обновляется автоматически</span></p><p style="text-align: center"><b><a href="regions.php?id=???????????">Назад</a></b><br/><b><a href="index.php?id=???????????">На главную</a></b></p></body></html>
```

Comment: Можно сюда еще `import`'ьі библиотек и урлу добавить? Ну или просто урлу

Comment: url'a именная, не хочу палить...

Comment: А это ваш сайт? если да, то имеет смысл сделать на бек"энде ссылку, на которой в json будут отдаваться эти данные. Проще и по ресурсам не так накладно... а если нет, то придется наверно регулярку писать... и на сколько я понял строки данных разделены `<br>`? если да, то полученую строку можно разбить на массив по `<br>`, а остальное в цикле регуляркой достать или почистить.

Comment: сайт не мой. можно по подробнее о "регулярке" ? Elements addrs = doc.getElementsMatchingText("-");
            try {
                String text = addrs.first().html();
                String[] textSplitResult = text.split("<br>").; Вот так, но много лишнего остаётся. Вот результат: - Рылеева, 39 (<span class="positive">Тек</span>), <span class="plain">БАР</span> Надо убрать что в скобках, а оставить"Рылеева, 39" и "БАР"

Comment: Я посмотрел про regex, думаю его вы имели ввиду. И пересмотрел требования, мне надо только "Улица,дом" и всё... Как порезать регексом, подскажите плёёёс !!

Comment: Я конечно в `JAVA` не силен... ноооо... смотри, ты получаешь тот самый заветный тег `<p>...</p>` с нужными данными, обзовем его `str`. далее `arr = str.split(RegEx[в духе что-то: <br/?>])`... и посмотри, что на выходе в `arr`?

Comment: не даёт прикрепить arr=str.split  SPLIT красным выделяет

Comment: у вас получилось?

Comment: пока нет.......занимаюсь